# Equivalence relation - Equilavence classes explanation

Tags: equivalence-relations

I have the following equivalence relation problem.

$Let \ R\subseteq 2^S*2^S = \{(A,B):|A\cap T|=|B \cap T|\}\  where\ S=\{0,1,2\} \ and \  T=\{1,2\} \ Show \  that \ R \ is \ a \ equivalence \ relation \ to \ 2^S \ and \  describe \ the \ equivalence  \ classes\ $

I understand that in order to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation I need to show that is $R$ is symmetric, reflexive and transitive.

Though I have two questions.

1. What the result of $2^S$ will be?
2. What steps do I need to follow to find the equivalence classes of an equivalence relation?

Comment: I think you meant $\;2^s= P(S)=$ the set of all subsets of $\;S\;$, and then $\;R\subset 2^S\times 2^S\;$ . What you mean by (1) is beyond my understanding, and about (2): there are only $\;8\;$ elements in $\;2^S\;$ so it shouldn't be that hard to do the actual partition of $\;2^S\;$ by equivalence classes. For example, $\;[\emptyset]=\{\emptyset\,,\,\{2\}\}\;$

Comment: I thought 2^S to be power. I guess I missed the symbolism of the power Set. 1 is now understood. About 2 I still have a hard time understanding how you found [0]={0,{2}}

Comment: Nice, now try to separate all the elements in $\;2^S=P(S)\;$ in different equivalence classes.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already gave you an example in the comment. For another one:

$$|\{1\}\cap T|=1\implies X\in\left[\,\{1\}\,\right]\iff |X\cap T|=1$$

so for example, we have in this case

$$\{1\}\,,\,\{0\}\,,\,\{0,2\}\,,\,\{1,2\}\in\left[\,\{1\}\,\right]$$

Now you **try** other cases.

Comment: I think I got it.

Will the answer(to my problem) be
                   [0]={{e},{0}} 
                   [1]={{1},{2},{0,1},{0,2}}
                   [2]={{1,2},{0,1,2}}
?

Comment: Observe that $\;[1]=[2]\;$ so your last one cannot be right, and in fact observe that $$|\{0,1,2\}\cap T|=2\neq 1=|\{1,2\}\cap T|$$

Comment: You are right. T is actually {1,2} and not {0,1} .